# TFS Build doesn't build with WebAPI project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, tfs, msbuild

I created simple WebAPI project:
[image]

Then I checked in to TFS and for some reason clean project doesn't build with msbuild on TFS.

Errors I get are following:
http://pastebin.com/ZPBEFcPN

Packages content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript" version="0.15.0-build58334" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Csproj content:
http://pastebin.com/VR2iXs2A

This is a project made from scratch, nothing added.

Comment: You need to post the contents of your .csproj files.  And of your "packages.config" if you have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I forgot to enable "Restore Nuget packages" option on build step.. don't ask..
[image]

Just to mention correct way to restore packages as per v2.7+ is to add Nuget installer step before build step:
[image]

Comment: No.  http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html "In the old way, you right click on your solution in VS and choose Enable package restore. This causes VS to modify your csproj files, and create .nuget folder containing nuget.exe and some other files."  Follow the steps at his blog....and if that doesn't "auto-work", then put in the command line restore method....from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
nuget.exe restore MySolution.sln
```

or

```
nuget.exe restore MyCsProj.csproj
```

before you attempt the tfs build.
Aka, on the TFS machine.

This is the "newer" way of restoring packages.

From

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

*Important: Nuget Automatic Package Restore has changed in Nuget 2.7+. **Do not mix 'old' and new methods for automatic package restoration.** For more information, see Common Issues with Automatic Package Restore, below.*

Since you "checked that box"  you may have to follow these instructions.

https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore/Migrating-to-Automatic-Package-Restore

Comment: I get this error: nuget.exe : The term 'nuget.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You have to install it (via download it and place it somewhere) on the TFS machine.  And use the full path.  ex:   c:\MyProgFiles\Nuget\v3.3.0\nuget.exe    (get it at : https://dist.nuget.org/index.html ).... then make the build script run the "c:\MyProgFiles\Nuget\v3.3.0\nuget.exe" MySolution.sln.  Use macros instead of hard coded paths where possible.

Comment: Please read http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html as well for tips about the "new way"

Comment: How do you install it on TFS machine?

Comment: You don't download and install TFS in this case.  You download the nuget.exe (from the download link I gave in the comments) and file-copy it to somewhere on the build machine.

Comment: I never accessed tfs build machine. Is that like virtual machine or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVC Nuget packages you should enable Nuget restore.

If you aren't using the Nuget packages you need to use the bin deployed MVC references by right clicking on the project and choosing "Add Deployable Dependencies".

[image]

Comment: nuget restore is enabled on solution level